# puppet master monitoring

Tags: monitoring, puppet

I have installed puppetmaster in ubuntu 10 and i have installed puppet in all my clients. I have joined all my puppet clients with puppet master. Tell me how to list all the running services of my client (like nagios,apache,mysql etc) in my puppet master console?
or simply how to monitor services running in client using master master console?
thanks in advance

Comment: Using puppet master you cannot check running services on all clients, better to use clusterssh its very use full.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read the Documentation for Puppet it offers lots of different features. And I would probably sling this on server fault instead on ask Ubuntu, might get a little better response on there.

http://docs.puppetlabs.com/

You will need to learn the syntax for Puppet

```
service { "apache2":
  ensure => "running",
}
```

Above is an example of code to check that the apache2 service is running. Its really worth reading through the docs though because they are very useful. Also below is a link to a puppet cookbook of little snippets of code. Again very good and can be used to hack together your own stuff.

Thanks
William

http://www.puppetcookbook.com/

Comment: hi thanks:) already I have seen through these. The point is where do I declare the services code snippet in my master. I mean which config file am I suppose to edit/include. (IAM NEW TO PUPPET) thanks in adv.

Answer (score 0):

Puppet's primary focus is service provisioning. A puppet node (running the puppet agent) is hooked up to a puppet master, and receives a catalogue of resources and services that should be made available on the puppet node. It does not provide an out of the box facility to monitor all running processes on puppet nodes.

That said, once each node has finished running through the catalogue of resources provided by the puppet master, it logs the state of each resource (including any errors), and posts this log back to the puppet master for later analysis. A separate puppet application (the Puppet Dashboard) can analyse these logs to produce a web-accessible console of the state of your entire puppet-managed environment, which is very useful. That may give you an approximation of the functionality you are asking about.

This article on [installing Puppet Dashboard](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/dashboard/manual/1.2/bootstrapping.html) should get you going.